# For Loop: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying, using the below code, to get for a set of portfolios (all contained in sheetnames): the performance of each single asset strategy and the total return. For that, I am trying to multiply the daily weights for each i portfolio (Data[i]) with the daily asset performance of the relevant indices - both matrices are 250 rows x 47 columns

I can't get around the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'". I do understand I am trying to multiply a dictionary by floats but I tried to change the dictionary in Array for each iteration but it didn't work.

```
Perf={}
Total_Perf={}

for i in sheetnames:
   Perf[i]=Data[i]*TAA_Indices_Returns
   Perf[i]=((1+Perf[i]).cumprod()-1)*100
   Total_Perf[i]=DataFrame(((1+Perf[i].sum(axis=1)).cumprod()-1)*100,columns={'TAA Total Perf'})
```

I have around 40 different portfolios and would like to find a more elegant way to do this instead of writing 40 lines of code.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Arthur

Comment: Your `Data` object is a dict? What sort of data is stored in it, and in what form?

Comment: @jack6e `Data` is a dict indeed, it's a set of daily portfolio weights (floats in %) across 47 different asset classes for 40 portfolios (i.e. 40 matrices of 250X47). And I basically want to get another dict with the same matrices size but with the performance for each portfolio and asset

Comment: Can you post an example of a few of its items? And is `TAA_Indices_Returns` a constant or another list?

Comment: `TAA_Indices_Returns` is a constant array with the same asset classes (columns) and the same index (daily dates) as `Data`. The values of `TAA_Indices_Returns` are percentage returns. So in term of size/shape both are identical

Comment: I would recommend converting your `Data` object and `TAA_Indices_Returns` object to `Dataframes`, which will make it easier to join indices for calculations, and also let you use vectorization in your operations.

Comment: Thanks for you time @jack6e it actually worked fine using my code, I didn't check all the portfolios before but I noticed that in the few ones at the end, some values were not numbers. Thus, creating an error...... silly mistake!